# How is scrollTop in JQuery supposed to function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm confused about `scrollTop()`.
jQuery docs say it should be displaying a number that represents the scrollTop offset for a given element, but as it does in my own script, on their demo it returns "0".

Setting the scrollTop manually works great, as does using the `$(window).scrollTop()` command.

Does `scrollTop()` ONLY return values associated with elements that themselves contain scrollbars (such as an element with a CSS property of `overflow:scroll`)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It only follows that elements with scrollbars in positions other than the top would have a scrollTop of > 0. If you have an element without scrollbars then one would expect that their scrollTop position IS 0 as they have nowhere to scroll to.

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is.

EDIT: Just in case that it is not explained properly in the jQuery docs:

`scrollTop()` => position of scrollbar for element (window/div/anything scrollable)

`$("#element").offset().top` => position of element relative to page

`$("#element").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()` => position of element relative to scrolled area.

Comment: So for a common usage to scroll the window so that #element appears (stays) at the bottom of the window use: $(window).scrollTop($('#element').offset().top);